# How to get current logged-In User details?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I added to new properties to `ApplictionUser` and now i want to retrieve it ?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   [Required]
   [StringLength(50)]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [StringLength(50)]
   public string LastName { get; set; }

   //....
}
```

> I tried to retrieved by using `User.Identity...` but i can't get first&last names?

How to do that ? I shall be very **thankful**.

Answer (score 3):

I retrieved the firstName and SecondName in this way:

**Step 1.**

```
// DbContext.
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

public HomeController()
{
   _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
}
```

**Step 2.**

```
// Getting Id of Current LoggedIn User.
var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

**Step 3.**

```
var User = _context.Users.Single(user => user.Id == UserId);
```

> These steps worked for me.

Comment: probably it is better to inject `ApplicationDbContext ` through ctor instead of manual creating.

Comment: @AlbertK  Yes you are right. But i added because some people get confuse with that approach and i am one of them. that's why i used manual approach.

Comment: OK, but then you also should call `_context.Dispose()` method manually somewhere. It may be critical for the performance.

Comment: @AlbertK . Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`User.Identity` returns just an abstraction `System.Security.Principal.IIdentity` that doesn't contain any custom properties and `ApplicationUser` instance.

One of the option is to use [`UserManager<ApplicationUser>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2) that can be injected into the controller if you `Startup` class has config for `ASP.NET Core Identity`:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
```

It will return exactly `ApplicationUser` instance.

Another option is get the user from your `DbContext` directly (by default its name is `ApplicationDbContext`. It also can be injected into the controller).

```
var user = await db.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);
```

Comment: @RehanShah Has this answer solved your problem ? If solved then marked it as answer and if not then say further details about the problem you are facing.

Comment: No i not tried this one....i tried my own answer....that is given below.